# When to use sorts over another

Tags: java, sorting, binary, quicksort, mergesort

Among Quicksort, MergeSort, and Binary Insertion Sort, is there ever a situation to use any one of these over the other?

I know things like Quicksort can become problematic on an almost-sorted list (but I believe the random assignment of the pivot can eliminate the worst case time), so it may be better to use MergeSort. MergeSort may use more space than QuickSort, I'm not entirely sure and Merge may be better for LinkedLists.

And I'm guessing Binary Insertion Sort is better for smaller lists? If so, is there a threshold for using this or is the size just left up to interpretation? Like, if the list is size 3 should we use Binary Insertion sort over Quick or Merge?

Comment: Meta-comment: There are questions which ask about the best algorithm for a specific case, but none about the best algorithm in general; this might make a good wiki. Meta-meta-comment: “sort” has ceased to look like a word.

Comment: Agreed. "Best" questions really depend a lot on your situation. e.g.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry for the dumb questions. However, what does it mean to say that Quicksort is not adaptive? I've checked http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/quick-sort for this and I don't think that term is explained clearly enough.

Comment: There are dozens of posts about which sorting algo is best. Almost every one of them will tell you that it mostly depends on the data you're sorting - how much, what type, whether it's un/partially/mostly sorted already, etc. This question is unanswerable as it is - it's totally subjective, and any attempt to provide an answer would be guesswork. Voting to close.

Comment: I'd like to add that the most important difference between Quick sort and merge sort is the stability. Merge sort is stable and quick sort is not. If stability is important to your data - in many cases it is! - then Merge sort is the only viable choice in many cases. Interestingly there are many "what's the best algorithm" questions out there but several fail to point this difference out.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that this is asking for practical advice on how to sort stuff in Java.

My advice is that it is usually best to use `Arrays.sort(...)` and rely on the standard implementation's heuristics for deciding which sort algorithm to use.  You only need to worry about this if:

- you know that you will be sorting huge datasets,
- you know that your dataset is amenable to special sorting methods; e.g. counting sort, or
- profiling has told you that your use of the standard sort method is a performance bottleneck.

---

(It is implicit in my answer is that you *know* all about the characteristics of different sorting algorithms, as presented in any good data structures text book.  IMO, every programmer should know that stuff.)

Answer (score 0):

Stephens answer is correct, but I would just like to add something.  If you look in an algorithms book, they cover the efficiencies of each sorting method.  Sometimes if you know what your data will look like, a particular sorting algorithm will have a best case scenario that tends to it better than another algorithm.  Correct me if I'm wrong, anyone.